# Eclipse JavaDoc Generation fails with IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: html, eclipse, javadoc

When I attempt to export or generate a javadoc for any of my javadoc commented classes I was always getting an error, until recently where it has just been generating entirely empty html files.

This is the error I was receiving before:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_03
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Users\James\Workspace\TestCLASS.html.…
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.j…
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(…
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath…
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath…
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivile… Method)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClass…
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClass…
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLCl…
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLo…
at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLo…
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivile… Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URL…
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassL…
at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStr…
at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(…
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivile… Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getRes…
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarS…
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(Fac…
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newIn…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.b…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.b…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlD…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlD…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.…
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv… Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv…
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl…
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.j…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invo…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.star…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExec…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.jav…
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.b…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.b…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlD…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.A…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlD…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.…
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv… Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv…
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl…
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.j…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invo…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.star…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExec…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.…
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.jav…
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit…
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlD…
```

I believe it stopped this error around the time I started telling the wizard to put the html files into a folder named docs in my workspace, alas this folder just has one empty html file in by the name of one of the classes in my project (usually Stack.html or Entry.html)

Also I unfortunately deleted the TestClass class as it was just a test, but here's the Stack class that I cannot generate javadoc for:

```
/**
 * Provides the Classes necessary to create a Stack data structure.
 */
package courseworkone;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created on 22 Oct, 2012.
 *
 * @author James
 */
public class Stack {
/**
 * The dynamic array into which elements of the Stack are held.
 */
private ArrayList<Entry> array;
/**
 * The size of the Stack (The number of elements on the stack).
 */
private int size;

/**
 * Constructs an empty Stack with an initial size of 0.
 */
public Stack() {
    array = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    size = 0;
}

/**
 * Checks the number of elements in the stack.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in the stack
 */
public final int size() {
    return size;
}

/**
 * Adds an element to the stack, and increases the stack size by 1.
 *
 * @param i
 *            The element to be added to the stack
 */
public final void push(final Entry i) {
    // adds the Entry to the stack
    array.add(i);
    // increments the stack size by one
    size++;
}

/**
 * Returns the element on the top of the stack.
 *
 * @return the top element in the stack
 */
public final Entry top() {
    // gets the element at the end of the ArrayList (top element) and
    // returns it
    return array.get(size - 1);
}

/**
 * Returns the element on the top of the stack and then removes that element
 * from the stack.
 *
 * @return the top element in the stack
 */
public final Entry pop() {
    // stores the element at the end of the ArrayList in a temporary
    // variable
    Entry mostRecentEntry = array.get(size - 1);
    // removes the element from the end of the ArrayList
    array.remove(size - 1);
    // decrements the size of the stack by one
    size--;
    // returns the element at the end of the ArrayList
    return mostRecentEntry;
}
}
```

Ive also used the javadoc wizard to save the settings of the javadoc export as an Ant script, and here are its contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="javadoc">
    <target name="javadoc">
        <javadoc access="public" author="true" classpath="C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar;C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar" destdir="C:\Users\James\workspace\docs" doctitle="Stack Implementation" nodeprecated="false" nodeprecatedlist="false" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" packagenames="courseworkone,testcourseworkone" source="1.7" sourcepath="src;test" splitindex="true" use="true" version="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here is the Console Output from the Ant Build Run:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012
Setting ro project property: ant.file ->     C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\javadoc.xml
Buildfile: C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\javadoc.xml
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\javadoc.xml with URI = file:/C:/Users/James/workspace/2ndYearWork/SoftEngCoursework1/javadoc.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> javadoc
Project base dir set to: C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1
 +Target: 
 +Target: javadoc
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
Setting ro project property: ant.project.invoked-targets -> javadoc
Adding reference: eclipse.ant.targetVector
Build sequence for target(s) `javadoc' is [javadoc]
Complete build sequence is [javadoc, ]
javadoc:
parsing buildfile     jar:file:/C:/Users/James/Documents/Eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI =     jar:file:/C:/Users/James/Documents/Eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v20120321-1730/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
  [javadoc] scanning C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\src for packages.
dirset: Setup scanner in dir      C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\src with patternSet{ includes: [courseworkone, testcourseworkone] excludes: [] }
  [javadoc] scanning C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\test for packages.
dirset: Setup scanner in dir     C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\test with patternSet{ includes: [courseworkone, testcourseworkone] excludes: [] }
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javadoc.exe' with arguments:
  [javadoc] '-public'
  [javadoc] '-d'
  [javadoc] 'C:\Users\James\workspace\docs'
  [javadoc] '-splitindex'
  [javadoc] '-use'
  [javadoc] '-doctitle'
  [javadoc] 'Stack Implementation'
  [javadoc] '-classpath'
  [javadoc]     'C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar;C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar'
  [javadoc] '-version'
  [javadoc] '-author'
  [javadoc] '-sourcepath'
  [javadoc]     'C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\src;C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\test'
  [javadoc] '-source'
  [javadoc] '1.7'
  [javadoc] 'courseworkone'
  [javadoc] 'testcourseworkone'
  [javadoc] 
  [javadoc] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
  [javadoc] not part of the command.
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javadoc.exe' with arguments:
'-public'
'-d'
'C:\Users\James\workspace\docs'
'-splitindex'
'-use'
'-doctitle'
'Stack Implementation'
'-classpath'
'C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar;C:\Users\James\Documents\Eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar'
'-version'
'-author'
'-sourcepath'
'C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\src;C:\Users\James\workspace\2ndYearWork\SoftEngCoursework1\test'
'-source'
'1.7'
'courseworkone'
'testcourseworkone'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package courseworkone...
  [javadoc] Loading source files for package testcourseworkone...
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_03
  [javadoc] Building tree for all the packages and classes...
  [javadoc] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
  [javadoc]     at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:202)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1016)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:357)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:352)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:351)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:328)
  [javadoc]     at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:171)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1138)
  [javadoc]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:227)
  [javadoc]     at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(SecuritySupport.java:94)
  [javadoc]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(SecuritySupport.java:87)
  [javadoc]     at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:248)
  [javadoc]     at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:221)
  [javadoc]     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:126)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:88)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:117)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:186)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:183)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
  [javadoc] com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:95)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:117)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:186)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:183)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
  [javadoc] com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:190)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:183)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
  [javadoc] Generating C:\Users\James\workspace\docs\courseworkone\Entry.html...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

I have no idea why I cannot generate javadocs properly

Any ideas?

Comment: could you post javadoc for the TESTClass java class?

Comment: Have done so above, thanks for replying.

Comment: did you solve this someway?

Answer (score 9):

I checked your code/doc and it seems ok to me. I tested with different version of JavaDoc. So i checked for the specific exception. I found this: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6219854.

They suggest to remove classpath as enviroment variable. Since you are using Eclipse, building and generating javadoc does not require further configuration outside the IDE. Check your variables and remove any unnecessary configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried deleting the classpath with no success unfortunately.

Comment: how do you generate javadoc? Are you using  `Generate Javadoc...` from  `Project` menu? Or different?

Comment: if you use Eclipse Javadoc wizard you could create an ant task to see what actually are your enviroment variables

Comment: Im generally generating the javadocs via Project --> Generate Javadoc...
However I have no success when I select a project and try to export a javadoc either.
Also I have run the javadoc wizard and saved the settings of the javadoc export as an Ant Script, I will amend its contents to my question above.

Comment: Run the Ant script with options (just use the second menu item 'Ant build..' and add to -verbose and -debug to arguments of main section. Run ant (if you experience that javadoc.exe is missing, add PATH variable to enviroment section using the path of your javadoc executable). Put your console result.

Comment: Thanks for replying, have added the console result above.

Comment: I know that this is not best way to solve, but for the moment I suggest you to do a fresh new install of the JDK in a folder without spaces and parenthesis since the decode function is the one that fires exception. Before this you can try to do dir /x on the C:\ folder and change JAVA_HOME and PATH (if any) from c:\program files (x86) to something like c:\progra~1

Comment: Up voted. I get the above error when I had CLASSPATH variable set.

Comment: I get this error outside of Eclipse, despite having no CLASSPATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you use eclipse and meet this error, please delete the environment variable of **classpath** as it is mentioned in the most voted answer above and **close and restart your software**. If you do not close and restart, (like me) the error may still exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse please check if the InstalledJRE's point to **JAVA_HOME** and nothing else. I had configured it to point **JAVA_HOME/jre** which was the problem.