# JavaDocs throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea and when I go tho generate the JavaDocs (via Tools -> Generate JavaDoc), I get thrown an IllegealArgumentException with no information about what is going wrong.

This occurs when testing with each individual file within my module even if there is no JavaDoc comments.

Here is an example of stack trace I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:202)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1204)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:525)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath.access$100(URLClassPath.java:64)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:239)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:250)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:601)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:599)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:598)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:623)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:293)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:89)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:120)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:189)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:205)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:189)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:137)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:82)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:80)
at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:310)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:189)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:366)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
javadoc: error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

From what I can tell, it's not really telling me much about the actual error. Here is an example file that I have tried generating JavaDocs for:

```
package Network;

public class NetworkTags {

    public static final String OPEN_TAG = "<";
    public static final String CLOSE_TAG = "/>";

    public static final String NET_OPEN_TAG = "<NET>";
    public static final String NET_CLOSE_TAG = "</NET>";

    public static final String VERTEX_TAG = "VERTEX";
    public static final String EDGE_TAG = "EDGE";

    public static final String REL_TAG = "REL";
    public static final String TYPE_TAG = "TYPE";
    public static final String COST_TAG = "COST";
    public static final String NAME_TAG = "NAME";

    public static final String SOURCE_TAG = "SOURCE";
    public static final String TARGET_TAG = "TARGET";

    public static final String FROM_TAG = "FROM";
    public static final String TO_TAG = "TO";
}
```

Using Java 8 and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1

Comment: Maybe this topic is related to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183675/eclipse-javadoc-generation-fails-with-illegalargumentexception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
You shold remove CLASSPATH enviroment variable.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue for me, too!

Comment: How/why is javadoc using the CLASSPATH env variable? I have %CATALINA_HOME% so I guess it can't process the percent sign but how do I get javadoc to run without changing my environment variable? I tried renaming CLASSPATH to CLASSPATH2 (the actual env var) but that didn't help.  "javadoc: error - Error decoding percent encoded characters"

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes if your classpath contains % init.

Comment: kay but % is a valid character to have in the classpath. Not sure how to get mvn release to work unless I just skip the javadoc with -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is facing this issue during the maven build, then comment on the maven plugin `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin` to avoid the error

Comment on the below plugin in `pom.xml`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```