# Error decoding percent encoded characters

Tags: java, maven-javadoc-plugin

I want to build a project and the following error occurs.
My colleagues can build it without any problem.
The error occurs since I've got a new laptop.

Does somebody has any idea?

```
>[INFO] 
Loading source files for package xxx...
Loading source files for package xxx...
Loading source files for package xxx...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_151
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Eigene Dateien\Documents\workspace\xxx.html...
1 error
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.042 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-09T09:56:09+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/326M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:jar (attach-javadocs) on project xxx: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error decoding percent encoded characters
[ERROR] at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:216)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1241)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:560)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:555)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:554)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:484)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath.access$100(URLClassPath.java:65)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:266)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:277)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:601)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:599)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next(URLClassLoader.java:598)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:623)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next(CompoundEnumeration.java:45)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(CompoundEnumeration.java:54)
[ERROR] at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:354)
[ERROR] at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
[ERROR] at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:293)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML(LayoutParser.java:89)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(ClassBuilder.java:120)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(HtmlDoclet.java:189)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFiles(AbstractDoclet.java:194)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:139)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:82)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:80)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:310)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:189)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:366)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
Command line was: C:\java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe @options @packages
```

When I skip creating javaDoc with `maven.javadoc.skip` and edit the build-plugins `maven-deploy-plugin` and `maven-javadoc-plugin` it will be build successful.

Comment: "Error decoding percent encoded characters" seems like a pretty clear error message you could search for. What did you find?

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157112/javadocs-throwing-illegalargumentexception

Thank you!